# iOS Metal Possible to conditionally encode commands to command buffer

Tags: ios, metal

I have this situation where all of my pipeline can be run on a single command buffer except two compute kernels. I have to check results of the last kernel to encode command A or command B next.

Pseudo flow of code :

```
Command Buffer 1: commandEncoder1 -> dispatchThreads , commandEncoder2 -> dispatchThreads 
Check output of commandEncoder2, if it is 1 then commandEncoder3 -> dispatchThreads else commandEncoder4->dispatchThreads.
```

Right now, I have to WaitForCompletion on CommandBuffer1, check for results and start a new CommandBuffer with either commandEncoder3 or commandEncoder4 based on results from commandEncoder2.

Is there a way to do the same without committing the command buffer? I lose about 3.2ms from committing to dispatching a new commandBuffer, and I really need those 3.2ms to speed up my processing.